# Format FilterAttribute result using Strategy Pattern in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, design-patterns

I've created an action filter to return custom result in `ActionFilterAttribute` using `context.result`:

```
public class ResultApi : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ResposeFormat resposeFormat;

    public ResultApi(ResposeFormat resposeFormat)
    {
        this.resposeFormat = resposeFormat;
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        resposeFormat.ContextResult(context);
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

I am using the strategy pattern to format the result:

```
public abstract class ResposeFormat
{
    public abstract void ContextResult(ResultExecutingContext context);
}
```

And, here are different implementations of my Formatter:

**OkResult :**

```
public abstract class OkResultFormatter : ResposeFormat
{
    public override void ContextResult(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is OkResult okResult)
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new ReturnResult(true, StatusCode.Success)) { StatusCode = okResult.StatusCode };
    }
}
```

**BadRequestResult :**

```
public abstract class BadRquestObjectresultFormatter : ResposeFormat
{
    public override void ContextResult(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is BadRequestObjectResult badRequestObjectResult)
        {
            var message = badRequestObjectResult.Value.ToString();
            if (badRequestObjectResult.Value is SerializableError errors)
            {
                var errorMessages = errors.SelectMany(p => (string[])p.Value).Distinct();
                message = string.Join(" | ", errorMessages);
            }
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new ReturnResult(false, StatusCode.BadRequest, message)) { StatusCode = badRequestObjectResult.StatusCode };
        }
    }
}
```

When I pass the `context` to the `resposeFormat.ContextResult(context);`, I want it to find the type of request and use the `OkResultFormatter` or `BadRquestObjectresultFormatter` .

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change things a little bit.

First of all, you have to add an abstract `get-only` property to your `ResultTypeToFormat` to determine which typeof `ObjectResult` should each implementation handle:

```
public abstract class ResponseFormatter
{
    public abstract Type ResultTypeToFormat { get; }

    public abstract void ContextResult(ResultExecutingContext context);
}
```

And accordingly, you have to change implementations like below:

```
public class OkResultFormatter : ResponseFormatter
{
    public override Type ResultTypeToFormat => typeof(OkObjectResult);

    public override void ContextResult(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new ReturnResult(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }
}

public class BadRequestResultFormatter : ResponseFormatter
{
    public override Type ResultTypeToFormat => typeof(BadRequestObjectResult);

    public override void ContextResult(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Perform other bad request stuff here ...
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new ReturnResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
    }
}
```

With these changes, now you have to register all result formatters in your DI Container like this:

```
services.AddScoped<ResponseFormatter, OkResultFormatter>();
services.AddScoped<ResponseFormatter, BadRequestResultFormatter>();
```

Finally, you can format results dynamically in your **Filter Attribute**:

```
public class CustomResultFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ResponseFormatter> _responseFormatters;

    public CustomResultFilterAttribute(IEnumerable<ResponseFormatter> responseFormatters)
    {
        _responseFormatters = responseFormatters;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        Type resultType = context.Result.GetType();

        ResponseFormatter appropriateFormatter = _responseFormatters
            .Single(formatter => formatter.ResultTypeToFormat == resultType);

        appropriateFormatter.ContextResult(context);
    }
}
```

Here's also the sample project in Github: [Sample project](https://github.com/MoienTajik/FilterAttributeStrategyPattern)